# Is there a way to force a mailto to launch Outlook (despite the default Email app setting in windows)

Tags: windows, email, outlook, default, mailto

I have a link in a web app that uses mailto: to launch an email (with default values for To, Subject, and Body).  That said, when this link is clicked by an end user, it opens with whatever default Email app they have setup in Windows.  All of my end users have Outlook, and some have (likely unintentionally) selected values other than Outlook as their default Email app.  This became apparent, this morning, when one of my end users complained and I found their default Email app was simply Chrome.

Is there a way to force the mailto: command to launch Outlook despite the end users default Email app value?

Comment: No, it would be horrible for user experience and ultimately perhaps even security.

Comment: You can't force a specific browser either, when you click a `http` lik then whatever the user has installed to handle `http` gets called. What would you do when the user doesn't have the mail client you want? The whole thing would also be a huge security problem if your website could just start random programs.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea but you can force another application assuming it is also registered as some type of protocol/file handler.

Use `ShellExecuteEx` with `SEE_MASK_CLASSNAME` or `SEE_MASK_CLASSKEY` and lpClass/hkeyClass to the applications progid under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT (Outlook.xyz or something like that).

See also:

- [How do I ShellExecute a file, but with a specific program instead of the default program?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171220-00/?p=97615)

Comment: Is it available for web pages?

Comment: No. This is a C API but you could call it from C#, VB, Python or Powershell. It very old versions if Internet Explorer you might have VBscript but not enough control to do this.

Comment: The original post mentions a web app - `I have a link in a web app that uses mailto`. How can `ShellExecuteEx` be called then?

Comment: Depends on what the OP means by web app. If it runs in a normal browser then no, it is not possible. If it something that hosts a web view, then yes, it is probably possible, https://felixrieseberg.com/using-native-windows-features-from-electron/ etc.

Comment: Well, I didn't find such nuances in OP or in your answer. In most cases it is not applicable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to force a specific email client on the end-user machine using the `mailto` protocol. Read more about possible parameters for the [mailto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa767737(v=vs.85)) protocol in MSDN or MDN.

You may consider automating Outlook from a web browser, but only Internet Explorer understands and aware about COM automation. Other web browsers can't use automation and is not aware about COM for security reasons.